# Dynamic SQL is not allowed

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure which looks like below

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS create_temp_table_from_procedure_name;
CREATE PROCEDURE create_temp_table_from_procedure_name(IN new_log_id INT,IN latitude DECIMAL(18,5),IN longitude DECIMAL(18,5),IN newRouterId VARCHAR(255)) 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE procedure_name_value VARCHAR(255);
        DECLARE create_table_query TEXT; -- Increased the length for the query
    
        -- Set the procedure_name_value to the desired procedure name
        SELECT procedure_name INTO procedure_name_value FROM debug_procedure_log WHERE log_id = new_log_id;
    
        -- Construct the CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE query
        SET @create_table_query = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ', procedure_name_value, ' AS (
            SELECT *
            FROM waypoint
            WHERE (
                waypoint.company_id IN (SELECT CompanyId FROM router WHERE RouterId = newRouterId)
                OR waypoint.company_id = 0
            )
            AND waypoint.waypointType != 134
            AND ST_CONTAINS(area, POINT(latitude, longitude))
        )');
    
        -- Execute the dynamic query
        PREPARE stmt FROM @create_table_query;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

and i am calling this procedure from a trigger like below

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS after_insert_debug_procedure_log;
            CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_debug_procedure_log
                AFTER INSERT ON debug_procedure_log
                FOR EACH ROW
                BEGIN
                    CALL create_temp_table_from_procedure_name(NEW.log_id,NEW.latitude,NEW.longitude,NEW.RouterId);
                END
            ");
```

but when some records are inserted in debug_procedure_log table it give following error
Feature not supported: 1336 Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger

Comment: From the MySQL manual: 'There are limitations on what can appear in statements that a trigger executes when activated:  The trigger cannot use the CALL statement to invoke stored procedures that return data to the client or that use dynamic SQL' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: It's not a good idea to create tables during a trigger anyway. Keep in mind triggers execute _for each row_ inserted by the action that spawned the trigger. Your procedure would fail anyway if you did an INSERT that creates two or more rows. Or even if you did two inserts serially. I recommend to create the table using code in your client application, before running the INSERT.

Comment: Instead of a trigger, you could use a scheduled event that checks for new records in debug_procedure_log at regular intervals and then calls the stored procedure.